# DATA_NOT_ENOUGH error when uploading mission waypoints to DJI drone (A3)

Tags: dji-sdk

When trying to start a new waypoint mission while one is already in progress, I usually get a `OpenProtocol::ErrorCode::MissionACK::WayPoint::DATA_NOT_ENOUGH` error when I try to upload the first waypoint. Strangely, if I stop the mission afterwards and try uploading again, it works.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any detailed documentation on what this error means.

Here's my code (note that it's the onboard SDK, not the mobile SDK; the code is Java calling into native code; interface generated by SWIG):

```
public void uploadWaypointMissionImpl(@NonNull DroneMission mission) throws DroneException{
    WayPointInitSettings wpis = newMissionSettings(mission);

    MissionManager missionManager = vehicle.getMissionManager();
    WaypointMission wptMission;
    int wpcount = missionManager.getWayptCounter();
    if (wpcount > 0){
        wptMission = missionManager.getWpMission();
        wptMission.stop(REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS);
        wptMission.init(wpis, REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS);
    } else{
        missionManager.initWaypoint(wpis, REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS));
        wptMission = missionManager.getWpMission();
    }

    if (wptMission == null)
        throw new DroneException("Failed to initialize mission manager");

    int pointCount = mission.getNavPoints().size();
    logger.i("Waypoint mission created, uploading %d points", pointCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; ++i){
        WayPointSettings wp = newWayPointSettings(mission, i);
        wptMission.uploadIndexData(wp, REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS).getAck(); // <-- ERROR HERE
    }
}


private static WayPointInitSettings newMissionSettings(@NonNull DroneMission mission){
    WayPointInitSettings wpis = new WayPointInitSettings();
    wpis.setMaxVelocity(mission.getVelocityMps());
    wpis.setIdleVelocity(mission.getVelocityMps());
    wpis.setTraceMode((short)(!mission.isInPlace() && Prefs.drone.traceMode().get() ? 1 : 0));
    wpis.setRCLostAction((short)(Prefs.drone.rcLostMode().get() ? 1 : 0));
    wpis.setGimbalPitch((short)(Prefs.drone.gimbalPitchAutoMode().get() ? 1 : 0));
    wpis.setYawMode((short)0);
    wpis.setExecutiveTimes((short)1);
    wpis.setFinishAction((short)4);
    wpis.setLatitude(0.0);
    wpis.setLongitude(0.0);
    wpis.setAltitude(0.0f);
    wpis.setIndexNumber((short)mission.getNavPoints().size());

    Uint8Array reserved = new Uint8Array(16);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
        reserved.setitem(i, (short)0);
    }
    wpis.setReserved(reserved.cast());

    return wpis;
}



private static WayPointSettings newWayPointSettings(@NonNull DroneMission mission, int index){
    WayPointSettings wp = new WayPointSettings();
    wp.setDamping(Prefs.drone.dampingDistanceM().get());
    wp.setGimbalPitch(Prefs.drone.gimbalPitch().get().shortValue());
    wp.setYaw(Prefs.drone.yawDeg().get().shortValue());
    wp.setTurnMode((short)(Prefs.drone.turnModeCounterClockwise().get() ? 1 : 0));
    wp.setActionTimeLimit(100);

    wp.setHasAction((short)0);
    wp.setActionNumber((short)0);
    wp.setActionRepeat((short)0);

    Uint8Array commandList = new Uint8Array(16);
    Uint16Array commandParameter = new Uint16Array(16);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
        commandList.setitem(i, (short)0);
        commandParameter.setitem(i, 0);
    }
    wp.setCommandList(commandList.cast());
    wp.setCommandParameter(commandParameter.cast());

    NavPoint point = mission.getNavPoints().get(index);
    wp.setLongitude(point.getLocation().getLngRad());
    wp.setLatitude(point.getLocation().getLatRad());
    wp.setAltitude((float)Math.ceil(point.getCruisingAltitude() - mission.getTakeoffAltitudeMeters()));
    wp.setIndex((short)index);

    return wp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Waypoint mission needs a minimum of 3 waypoints when i tried it on an android device, try adding 2 more points but note that they must have 1 meter distance between each point

Edit: I added code for making waypoints and adding them to a list

```
// Create a waypoint instance
Waypoint mWaypoint1 = new Waypoint(Latitude, Longitude, altitude);
//check if the mission's builder is null
if (waypointMissionBuilder != null) {
        waypointList.add(mWaypoint1);
        waypointMissionBuilder.waypointList(waypointList).
        waypointCount(waypointList.size());
     }
else {
    waypointMissionBuilder = new WaypointMission.Builder();
    waypointList.add(mWaypoint1);
    waypointMissionBuilder.waypointList(waypointList).
    waypointCount(waypointList.size());
    }
```

You need to make a waypoint instance which has Lat,Long,Alt. give it the correct parameters and add it to the list then use the builder to config, upload and start the mission. In case the list's size is 2 or less the mission will give you a djiError when trying to use the config function.

Answer (score 0):

Hi，maybe you need to call the "wptMission.stop"before you start a new waypoint mission.All the data of this mission you write is uploaded to the flight controller,only when you call the "wptMission.stop",the flight controller will know you want to call other commands.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, stopping the waypoint mission before uploading the first waypoint doesn't help.